# Round numbers in concatenated labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I've created some multi-line labels in QGIS 2.18.12 using the expression:

```
 "PIPE_DIA"  || 'mm' ||  ' ' || "PIPE_MATRL" ||  '\n'  ||  'US Depth: ' ||   ( "START_COVELEV" - "START_INVELEV")  || '\n' ||  'DS Depth: ' ||  ( "END_COVELEV" - "END_INVELEV" )
```

All ELEV fields are double with precision to 3 decimal places.

The output however randomly spits out an extra 11 decimal places like this:
[image: Label_QGIS]

I've gone into label properties and set decimal places to 2 but it does nothing. I've also tried using the concat( function instead but it returns the same error.

Anyone have any ideas or work arounds?

Comment: I should add that it is occurring randomly on both the US Depth and the DS Depth labels but not every label.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround you can force the labels to round to the 3 decimals by adding the following expression before calculations:

```
"PIPE_DIA"  || 'mm' ||  ' ' || "PIPE_MATRL" ||  '\n'  ||  'US Depth: ' ||  round(( "START_COVELEV" - "START_INVELEV"),3)  || '\n' ||  'DS Depth: ' ||  round(( "END_COVELEV" - "END_INVELEV" ),3)
```

Notice the `round(( "START_COVELEV" - "START_INVELEV"),3)` and `round(( "END_COVELEV" - "END_INVELEV" ),3)`

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue with a particular release of Qt. Try an update to a later version of Qt, or update the version of the operating system you are using. This problem stopped for me when I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04